# Regex to match a string not followed by anything

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a regex sequence that will match the first item in the list below but not the other two, {Some-Folder} is variable.

```
http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}/
http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}/thing/key/
http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}/thing/119487302/

http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}/{something-else}
```

Essentially I want to be able to detect anything that is of the form:

```
http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}/
```

or

```
http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}
```

but not

```
http://www.url.com/{Some-Folder}/{something-else}
```

So far I have

```
http://www.url.com/[A-Z,-]*\/^.
```

but this doesn't match anything

Comment: end of line is represented by $. Add that to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://www.url.com/[^/]+/?$
```

Or, in the few parsers that use `\Z` as end of text,

```
http://www.url.com/[^/]+/?\Z
```

Answer (score 1):

I customized a [regex I've used for URL parsing before](https://gist.github.com/ohaaland/2952574), it's not perfect, and will need even more work once gTLD becomes more used. Anyway, here it is:

```
\bhttps?:\/\/[a-z0-9.-]+\.(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)\/[^\/\s]+(?:\/\b)?
```

You may want to add case insensitive flag, for whichever language you're using.

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/HyVXU30Hvp

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:
`(?m)http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/[^\/]+\/?$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?m)` : Set the `m` modifier which makes `^` and `$` match start and end of line respectively
- `http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/` : match `http://www.example.com/`
- `[^\/]+` : match anything except `/` one or more times
- `\/?` : optionally match `/`
- `$` : declare end of line

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kS7tH8)**

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this exact problem. aaaaaa123456789's answer almost worked for me. But the $ and \Z didn't work. My solution is:

```
http://www.url.com/[^/]+/?.{0}
```