# Followup regex, match item with Capital letter to start a part of a string

Tags: regex

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2058293/aaaaaa123456789

I was able to get a solution to this question
 [Regex to match a string not followed by anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957117/regex-to-match-a-string-not-followed-by-anything)

I had asked to be able to match items similar to

```
http://www.url.com/{A-Variable}/
```

and the given answer was `http://www.url.com/[^/]+/?$`, but then I realised that I actually need to match only the instances of A-Variable that begin with a capital letter.

such as

```
http://www.url.com/Something-Good/
http://www.url.com/Rollling-Stones/
http://www.url.com/Delightful/
```

but not

```
http://www.url.com/terminate/
http://www.url.com/permutate/
http://www.url.com/kidney-stones/
```

I've been trying something like `http://www.url.com/[A-Z,-].[^/]+/?$`

The doco seems to say that [A-Z] will only match capital letters but it seems to match any letter for me, and therefore I can't make much progress.

Comment: Try `http://www.url.com/[A-Z,-].[^/]+/?`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work according to RegEXRX

Comment: This is really [simple](http://regex101.com/r/bB4iQ8)

Comment: Thanks that looks good. My RegEXRX test software seems to match everything on your solution. So I suspect I should start using something else. The site you've linked to looks great.

Comment: Which solution worked for you? If this is solved, please select an answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
url\.com\/([A-Z]+[a-z\-]*)+\/
```

Comment: I entered http://www.url.com/\/([A-Z]+[a-z\-]*)+\//[^/]+/? and didn't get any matches for the items above.

Comment: Sorry thats "http://www.url.com/\/([A-Z]+[a-z\-]*)+\//[^/]+/?" I got kicked off the Internet and couldnt edit the one above

Answer (score 2):

What regex flavour/engine are you using? You need to ensure that case insensitivity is turned **off**.

Consider adding the mode modifier `(?-i)` (turns off case insensitivity) at the beginning of your regex.

```
(?-i)http://www.url.com/[A-Z,-].[^/]+/?$
```

This is not supported but all regex flavours.

Comment: I guess whichever flavour is built into Java. Thanks for the info.

Comment: This should work with Java. Let me know if it solved your issue!

Comment: @Bohemian what flavour are you using that does that?

Comment: I must have misread the `(?-I)` as `(?i)`. Sorry - looks fine. +1!